# mysql find record by field/column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

Hy everyone.
I working an app for android which is query result from database. the android side is OK, i can transfer data in and out from DB server to android. but i have difficulties in PHP and mysql stuff, specifically to find record by field/column value and print the row that matched the value i search.
Let's see this is my database structure :
database name is LBS, table name is information.

```
ID, NAME, JOB

1, john,   teacher
2, doe,    farmer
3, obama,  farmer
4, sweden, teacher
```

what syntax i can use to print row that have for example teacher value form JOB column ?, so the output is like this :

```
1, john,  teacher
4, sweden,teacher
```

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: *"GIVE a man fish and feed him for a day. SHOW a man HOW to fish and you will feed him for life."*

Answer (score 2):

Just make a where condition

```
SELECT * FROM information WHERE job = 'teacher';
```

Then you will get output as

```
ID |NAME   |JOB
---|-------|------
1  |john   |teacher
4  |sweden |teacher
```

Comment: @user2108272 try given query and you will get records whoes job is teacher. :)

Comment: It looks like the OP wants everything given on a "Silver Platter" - *"what syntax i can use to print row that have for example teacher value form JOB column ?, so the output is like this :"*

Comment: thanks the code is works in mysql (i tested it in phpmyadmin).but how to print/echo this result with PHP ?

Comment: this is my query now i confused how to echo the $result,  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Information WHERE job='teacher'");

Comment: @user2108272 Does the word `while` mean anything to you? ;-)

Comment: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo $row['NAME'];}  
is that correct sir ? but that didn't display anything (that code supossed to print the NAME value right ?)

Comment: @user2108272 What do you have set for `$result`?

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM information WHERE JOB = 'teacher'`

Answer (score 0):

Try for outputting as string:

> ```
> SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', ID, NAME, JOB) WHERE JOB='teacher'
> ```